Как добавить классы Bootstrap в компонент React? Kotlin + React
Требуется отрисовать кнопку с использованием Bootstrap. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в элемент button добавить классы из Bootstrap?
Ниже представлен пример кода рендеринга кнопки.
override fun ChildrenBuilder.render() {
  button {
    css {
      backgroundColor = NamedColor.lightgreen
    } 
    +"Sample"
  }
}

